# Nikon Df: a way to send photos to ipad in real time

Tags: nikon, accessories, nikon-df

gear question!

is there a way to connect a Nikon Df so that it sends what it sees to an ipad.

it could be each photo taken, or ideally video feed before the photo is taken.

i don't care if its wireless, i've tried WU-1a adapter and it's absolute garbage (slow buggy). so thinking a wired connection could be a lot more usable.

***solved***

as per the answer i tried a few things..

**didn't work:**

- cable tethered to ios device (supposedly works with Lightroom on a laptop, but i couldn't find any software that works with iOS devices)
- using tether tools case air (not compatible with nikon df)

**worked:**

- cam ranger mini

Comment: How techie are you? Would you be interested in solutions which involve plugging a Raspberry Pi into the camera and configuring a bunch of stuff? What about solutions which involve a bit of programming?

Comment: @PeterTaylor i am a software engineer, but don't see how Raspberry Pi factors into this solution :)

Comment: My solution for my Nikon D40 was to set up an RPi with a wifi daemon and web daemon and connect phone/tablet to RPi by HTTP over wifi and RPi to camera by USB. Much cheaper than any third party hardware, but not as pretty and a bit more work to set up.

Comment: @PeterTaylor and it sounds like you can only use this solution at home.. i need something to work while shooting in the field .. impressive technological feat though!!!

Comment: I used it in the field with a small external battery, but I admit the "mount" was rather ad hoc: a small velcro pouch hanging off the strap.

Comment: @PeterTaylor hmm good idea. actually having a hard time finding a short usb cable for it. all the ones i am finding are 3 feet !

Comment: My external battery came with a cable about 5cm long.

Comment: @PeterTaylor any way you could help me find such a cable? i tried searching in all kinds of ways but 3 feet is the shortest that comes up.. ill try for "5cm" !

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Charge-Connector-Google-Huawei-ZenFone/dp/B01JUW2EFW/ ?

Comment: ah, your camera accepts usb-c ? interesting.. my Df needs some 9pin Nikon port :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking about is called *tethering*, whether it's wired or wireless.

I own and use a [CamRanger](https://camranger.com) to wirelessly control, view, and preview images from my Nikon DSLR on my iOS and Mac devices.

Alternately, TetherTools has a bunch of resources for controlling particular cameras wired and/or wirelessly, using a bunch of different host computer software, and mobile devices: [Tethertools.com resources for Nikon Df](https://www.tethertools.com/camera/nikon-df/).

Comment: this is great thanks! are you able to control your camera from the device? that would be a big bonus!

Comment: Yes. Can select focus points, set exposure (shutter speed, aperture, ISO), picture mode settings, picture quality (jpeg, RAW), white balance, ... most things you would normally do. You can use it as an intervalometer, or for bracketing as well.

Comment: hmm the tethertools appears to be trying to sell me a cable for $100 as "tethering starter kit" :)

Comment: I find Tethertools to be more useful as an information resource, rather than a shopping resource. =)

Comment: i got the cable from TetherTools, but it doesn't look like there is a way to control the camera with a ios device wired via cable :(

Comment: looks like CamRanger will only work with some sort of radio controller ?

Comment: @SonicSoul No. CamRanger is essentially a wifi hotspot that has a cable connection to your camera, with the smarts to control your camera's settings, shutter, etc. Your phone, tablet, or computer connects to CamRanger's wifi, and can thus control your camera.

Comment: scottbb we're saying the same thing. i was just pointing out there doesn't seem to be a way to tether (control) my camera with ios device and a cable. looks like i need additional hardware components :(

Comment: @SonicSoul I see what you mean. The reason I objected is because when I hear "radio controller" in a photographic context, I think radio-signal flash triggers, etc. Different connotation. But no, I have not found a direct-wired controller for iOS devices.

Comment: such a bummer! i guess i'll be going to Adorama to spend a ton of $ to get this to work :(

Comment: @SonicSoul Yeah. And just to be clear, I don't want to paint the CamRanger as the rosiest thing ever. For instance, they make you register its serial number before the iOS software will work with it (at least they used, I haven't pulled it out in several months). The software isn't bad, but it does have some quirks. Overall, I am happy with the functionality, and I don't feel gouged. But as with all things that are niche-within-niche, it doesn't have the benefit of millions of users to have the product polished as much as I'd like. =)